# For loop not finding windows file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have a loop to open a file and find every file within but it wont find my file to open?

When i try to run i receive: - filenames.txt File not found - 0 files copied.

Code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ("C:\user\userdata\filenames.txt") do echo D|xcopy "C:\user\userdata\files\%%i" "C:\Output\" /i /z /y
pause
```

Comment: Remove the quotes in the parantheses (quotes->string).

Comment: Sorry but i dont follow?

Comment: `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("C:\user\userdata\filenames.txt")...`?

Comment: `for /F "usebackq delims=" ...`? And there is no need to echo `D` (Directory) into `xcopy` as the destination is terminated by a `\ `which indicates a directory anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes between the parantheses tells `for` to process the filename a s string, not as pointer to a file. Either remove the quotes, or use `usebackq` (makes sense to keep them, as a filename may contain spaces):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("C:\user\userdata\filenames.txt") do echo D|xcopy "C:\user\userdata\files\%%i" "C:\Output\" /i /z /y
```

Comment: Worked a charm! Thanks.